# X11 Forwarding on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I have a computer running Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS and wanted to know if it is possible to run GUI apps from it over X11 without having a GUI on the server? I also have programs that I want to run through Wine and forward the interface over X11. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean "without having a GUI on the server"? Installing GUI apps on the server will likely pull in an X server and various other "graphical" dependencies, but you don't need to be running, e.g., a desktop environment in order to use plain old X forwarding. You can also use something like XRDP to run a full GUI on the server and access it remotely which in my experience is usually a smoother experience overall. As for your second question, as long as the interface is displayed over X11 Wine shouldn't make a difference.